# Factoring tensors by linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Let $T_n$ be tensors $\left( V^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\right)$ of order $n$. Now let $\sim$ be equivalence on $T_n$ that $A\sim B$ iff there is regular matrix $M$ that $A\circ M = B$.

By $A\circ M$ I mean.
$$(A\circ M)(x_1,\dots,x_n) := A(Mx_1,\dots,Mx_n)$$
where $x_1,\dots,x_n \in V$ are any vectors.

I would like to understand $T_n\big /_\sim$ and I would like to uniquely describe element $[A]$ of $T_n\big /_\sim$ when $A\in T_n$ is given.

In case of $n=1$ is $T_1\big /_\sim$ trivial, it has two elements. Because elements of $T_1$ are just linear forms and any two nozero linear forms can be transformed each on another by some matrix.

But what happens for higher $n$?

And what happens if I let $M$ be only orthogonal?

---

**my progress**: Denote by $S_n \subset T_n$ the symmetric tensors. Than $S_2\big /_\sim$ is just a set of all possible signatures of quadratic forms.

Right now I don't have a time to write the proof down in full. But if follows from the fact that symmetric matrix $A$ can be written in the form:
$$ A = M D M^T = M \sqrt{|D|} S \sqrt{|D|} M^T $$
$M$ is orthogonal, $D$ is diagonal, and $S$ contains only $1,-1,0$.

I wonder if there is something like signature of cubic,quartic,... forms.

Actually I'm more interested in $S_n\big /_\sim$ more than $T\big /_\sim$. So if you can answer my question for $S_n$ please go ahead.